# IE10 media query not working

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have the following two media queries set up to target IE10, to display a div when the screen is at 1200px or less and for it to be removed when it's larger than 1200px, however it will only ever apply the second query 'display: block'. I tried re-ordering the media queries, thinking it might be a simple solution, however this didn't solve the problem. I'm not sure whether i'm missing something obvious with this or not?

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .image-feed-replace {
        display: none;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 1200px) and (-ms-high-contrast: active), (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
    .image-feed-replace {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These

Link: [CSS- Tricks](https://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/)

Link : [Usage of @Media Rule](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms530813(v=vs.85).aspx)

should solve your Problem.

Try this way also:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 1199px) and (max-width: 1200px){

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I didn't find any solutions here.

Comment: @JessCauchi: I have modified My answer .. Check that also. That is showing how you can use Media rules.

Comment: Just see if that helps you out. Yes it is proper. Even I have not used multiple but trying to help you by figuring myself. :)